# Platinum-carbon calayst in autoclave

Tags: materials

Is it safe to treat platinum-carbon catalyst in an autoclave at 200 °C for 24 h in inert (nitrogen) atmosphere? If no, can you suggest safety measures?

Comment: Do you mean "safe" for the humans doing the process, or "safe" for the catalyst?  I'm not aware of any significant dangers from heating the catalyst, assuming it is not freshly pulled from an anaerobic atmosphere containing hydrogen.  However I don't know if it will degrade the catalyst in any way.